# winforms how to launch ie with url to activex control

Tags: c#, winforms, activex

I am writing a Windows application and on the click event of a button I want to launch Internet Explorer (not default browser) along with an ActiveX control that I have a URL to.  Here's what I tried:

```
 private void myButton_ Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string startMyProcess;
        startMyProcess = "http://myservername/directory/myactivex.application";


        //Start my process
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = 
                new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", 
                     startMyProcess);
            Process.Start(startInfo);
            startInfo = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Your help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What isn't working? This does exactly what it should, opens IE to the URL specified. Also, catching a `Exception` only to throw it isn't good practice as its just wrapping what will happen anyway in an extra step.

Comment: what went wrong? Was an exception thrown? Did the program not launch at all?

Comment: Ended up being a network policy issue.  Thanks for the help.